# Apply a method to an array and return array value as a key

Tags: ruby

I would like to know if ruby has a builtin method to do the following.

from this array:

```
array = [:foo, :bar]
```

and this method:

```
def content_for_key key
  return :baz if key == :foo
  return :qux if key == :bar
end
```

and this call:

```
array.some_built_in_ruby_method(&:content_for_key)
```

we get:

```
{
  :foo => :baz,
  :bar => :qux,
}
```

Comment: Can you tell how the result is constructed? `content_for_key` returns `nil` for anything other than `:bar`, so what is the logic to build the result? Any time `content_for_key` returns `nil`, we map that to `:baz`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wrote it too fast. I edited my initial code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to convert each element to a `[key, value]` pair:

```
array.map { |key| [key, content_for_key(key)] }
#=> [[:foo, :baz], [:bar, :qux]]
```

followed by [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to transform the nested array into a hash:

```
array.map { |key| [key, content_for_key(key)] }.to_h
#=> {:foo=>:baz, :bar=>:qux}
```

Or you could use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to populate a hash while traversing the array:

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |key, hash| hash[key] = content_for_key(key) }
#=> {:foo=>:baz, :bar=>:qux}
```

Comment: My question is: "Does ruby offer a Array method taking a symbol `&:my_func` (like mao) and returning an hash with one key per array item and the value of this item would be `my_func(item)`

Comment: @DanielCosta maybe Ruby does have such method and I just prefer posing long-winded solutions instead. But that's rather unlikely ;-)

Comment: I actually implemented the `.to_h` earlier today before posting, was just wondering. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @DanielCosta: no, array doesn't have such method. Nor does anything else. It's just how `&:my_func` works. It generates a block which, when passed `elem`, runs `elem.my_func`. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like this. Although it lacks readability in comparison to the answer you already have

```
array = [:foo, :bar, :mnky]
def content_for_key key
  return :baz if key == :foo
  return :qux if key == :bar
end
array.zip(array.map(&method(:content_for_key))).to_h
#=> {:foo=>:baz, :bar=>:qux, :mnky => nil}

# or 

[array,array.map(&method(:content_for_key))].transpose.to_h
#=> {:foo=>:baz, :bar=>:qux, :mnky=>nil}
```